# How to get not initialised disk info C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to show data of not initialised HDDs? I need an app to show if there are any not initialised disks. Trying that:

```
DriveInfo[] disks = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

foreach(DriveInfo d in disks)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.Name + " " + d.DriveFormat);
}
```

But it shows only already formatted partitions

Comment: You can use WMI to retrieve that information